# too many parameters for this operator function

Tags: c++

First, I'm not good at english and also first time in StackOverflow, but I try to explain about my code's problem.

I was asked to make my own Vector(similar thing) from my professer, and there's a problem in fuction which returns a reference to the element at the requested position in the vector container. If the requested position is out of range, it should output some messages and terminate the program.

I should make this to Operator overloading, and this is my code.

```
        double operator [](int n, const MyDoubleVector& _mV)//The arror come out at this line.
    {
        if(n > num)//'num' is private reference in class to count array. it typed int.
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return &_mV.data[n];//'data' is private reference in class. It declare like 'double *data = new double [num];'
    }
```

I saw that sometimes 'friend' solve this, but when I put 'friend' in this line, it said me like "operator[] must be a member function."
 Finally, Ihave no idea how to do. Would you please help me?

Comment: You can not overload subscript operator that way and with more than one parameter. [This](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/) is useful to read.

Comment: Why do you need `MyDoubleVector` as a parameter? If the overload is part of the class then you can access everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the overload of operator[] as a member function of your class MyDoubleVector.
Here's the definition :

```
double & MyDoubleVector::operator[](int index);
```

Answer (score 0):

operator `[]` must be defined as a member of the class.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyDoubleVector
{
    MyDoubleVector()
    {}

    MyDoubleVector(MyDoubleVector const& other)
    {
        // very naiive copy constructor
        if (other.data)
        {
            std::for_each(other.data, other.data + other.num, [&](double val)
            {
                this->push(val);
            });
        }
    }

    MyDoubleVector& operator=(MyDoubleVector const& other)
    {
        auto temp = other;  // invoke copy constructor
        std::swap(num, temp.num);
        std::swap(capacity, temp.capacity);
        std::swap(data, temp.data);
        return *this;
    }

    ~MyDoubleVector()
    {
        delete [] data;
    }

    double& operator [](int n);
    /** either define the method inline like this...
    {
        if(n > num)
        {
            std::cerr << "MyDoubleVector::operator[]: index " << n << " out of range" << std::endl;
            std::exit(100);
        }

        return data[n];
    }
    **/

    void push(double val)
    {
        if (num == capacity)
        {
            more();
        }
        data[num++] = val;
    }

private:

    void more()
    {
        if (!data)
        {
            data = new double [10];
            capacity = 16;
        }
        else
        {
            auto newcapacity = capacity * 2;
            auto newdata = new double [newcapacity];
            std::copy(data, data + capacity, newdata);
            std::swap(data, newdata);
            capacity = newcapacity;
            delete [] newdata;
        }
    }

    int num = 0;
    int capacity = 0;
    double* data = nullptr;
};

/** ...
    ** or out of line like this
    **/

double& MyDoubleVector::operator [](int n)
{
    if(n > num)
    {
        std::cerr << "MyDoubleVector::operator[]: index " << n << " out of range" << std::endl;
        std::exit(100);
    }

    return data[n];
}


int main()
{
    MyDoubleVector v;
    v.push(10.0);
    v[1];
}
```